# Portico : Java.lang.OutofMemoryError java heap space

Tags: java, jvm, java-7

I am trying to use Portico in one of my projects for sharing objects over the network among the multiple instances of the same application running on several machines.

I am using Windows 7 64 bit.

So suppose there are 3 kinds of objects. A, B, C.

Size of Obj A is around : 300 bytes
Size of Obj B is around : 700 bytes
Size of Obj C is around : 1200 bytes

I am able to share the objA and objB between the applications. But as soon as I share the objC it throws an error in log that : Error in sending the message of length 1213 bytes. **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError java heap space.**

I am also tracking my application's heap size in VirtualVM. Following is the info that I retrieved.

**While sending objA :**
Max Heap Size around : 64 MB
Heap size : 2.5 MB
Used Heap : 1.8 MB

**While sending objB :**
Max Heap Size around : 64 MB
Heap size : 2.5 MB
Used Heap : 2.0 MB

NOTE here : The heap size shoots to 64 KB but used heap size remains almost same.

**While sending objC :**
Max Heap Size around : 64 MB
Heap size : 64 MB
Used Heap : 2.0 KB

So, I tried to increase the heap size using the following command :

**java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -jar portico.jar**

but then it threw and error : **Error: Could not find or load main class org.portico.rti.Main**

Then I tried to compile portico on windows 7 64 bit, it gave me some linking error related to JVM. I am using the latest JDK 1.7. And I was using server VM as client VM is not available in 64 bit.

So I tried building portico on 32 bit windows 7 using client VM. and it build successfully but again I was not able to locate Main class file in **codebase\build\java\classes\org\portico\rti\Main.class**. And hence, when I tried to use the same command as above along with classpath :

**java -cp ......\build\java\classes -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -jar portico.jar**

it again threw the same error : **Error: Could not find or load main class org.portico.rti.Main**

How do I solve this. It is driving me crazy. Please help me guys.

Comment: So to be more specific its like I am not able to send message of size more than 1KB. Has anyone come across this problem before ?